# imported function is not working when using it from another modules

Tags: python, import

I have been trying understand what is wrong with my code with no success...

I have two.py file which I have written  with some function **logs.py** supposed to write an input to a file 
and **monitor_mode.py** use thous function

When running the log.py as main everything just work fine and the file is created and written on, however when trying to use the same function in monitor_mode.py nothings seems to be written     to the files and I have no idea why

I did try to debug and the code is directed to to right function and everything is going as excepted except there is no creation or data written to the file

thanks for any help

**logs.py**

```
serviceList = 'serviceList.txt'
statusLog = 'statusLog.txt'


def print_to_file(file_name, input):
    with open(file_name, 'a+') as write_obj:
        write_obj.write(input + '\n')
    write_obj.close()


def add_timestamp(input):
    timestamp = '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime(
        "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'
    input = timestamp + '\n' + input
    return input


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import services

    for i in range(3):
        proc = services.list_of_process()
        proc = add_timestamp(proc)
        print_to_file(serviceList, proc)
```

**monitor_mode.py**

```
import logs
import services

serviceList = 'serviceList.txt'
statusLog = 'statusLog.txt'


def updates_log():
    proc = services.list_of_process()
    proc = logs.add_timestamp(proc)
    logs.print_to_file(serviceList, proc)
    print('Updates Logs\n' + proc)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(3):
        updates_log()
```

**EDIT1.1**
the above code is running on ubuntu16.8
when running the code on win10 machine its working just fine.

services.list_of_process() - return a string

Comment: Working as expected for me

Comment: both of the codes?

Comment: If one version is working and the other isn't please be specific about what the actual problem is.  And note that we are just guessing about what `services.list_of_process` returns